# Which python dependencies to install in Docker container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I'm building a docker image of a python Flask server and I was getting too many errors installing the dependencies in my `requirements.txt`.

I decided I would specify the version of each python package I was using in my requirements.txt to match the version installed on my PC (so, `flask==x.xx.x` instead of just `flask`). Since I was still getting errors and every version I changed just introduced another error, I just `pip freeze` on my PC's cmd and copied every python package I had installed on my PC with its version. It worked.

The problem is, I probably have a lot of python packages installed on my docker container that are absolutely not necessary. Is there a way to see which python packages are actually useful/used for my docker container? This attempt was the only thing that worked when building my docker container after a sea of endless errors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For future reference: you should be creating a virtual environment and install any packages specific to your project there, and then just `pip freeze` those into `requirements.txt`. Yes, you do need a nailed down list of the exact versions that you know your code works with. And you isolate your project in a virtual environment so you get _only_ the dependencies you need.